# How to check values of the .all() with flask-SqlAlchemy?

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, pdb

I'd like to check the values of all with `pdb` but the `p` did not output the values of all. But this code successfly can pass and `return 'success'`.　Also, the database has the correct values

flask code

```
    import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
    all = db.session.query(UserToken).filter(UserToken._token == _token).all()
    if not all:
         return 'error'
    return 'success'
```

debbuger result

```
(Pdb) p all
(Pdb) p db.session.query(UserToken).filter(UserToken._token == _token).all()
(Pdb)
```

Comment: It may be possible it is returning a list of `[None]`.  Also, avoid using all at two places as above it is confusing.

Comment: The code does not output [None] as you can see in the above debbuger result and it does not return 'error'. I'm looking for how to check values of all not .all().

Comment: It will not return 'error' as list is not empty. For example try this to understand:`v=[None]
if v:
    print('Yes')`. I am not sure whether it will solve anything but with the amount of code you have shared we cannot do much.